JFrog Jenkins artifactory plugin version 7 fails to create a build with JFrog declarative language
I fail to create a build due to permissions issue, while user got all permissions in the repository and image exists and looks fine in the repository:
Jenkins Failure:
10:43:31  INFO: Searching manifest in path: techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample/pr_103
10:43:31  May 30, 2024 7:43:31 AM org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerLogger info
10:43:31  INFO: Trying to download manifest from techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample/pr_103/manifest.json
10:43:32  May 30, 2024 7:43:32 AM org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerLogger info
10:43:32  INFO: Fetching details of published docker layers from Artifactory...
10:43:32  May 30, 2024 7:43:32 AM org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerLogger error
10:43:32  SEVERE: Failed to set properties to 'techops-docker-dev-local/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample/pr_103/sha256__882c413fce13b394543b13ad8d3a80559ee2d1d527fd88403a6a0eff90cffca4'
10:43:32  May 30, 2024 7:43:32 AM org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerLogger error
10:43:32  SEVERE: IOException: JFrog service failed. Received 403: {
10:43:32    "errors" : [ {
10:43:32      "status" : 403,
10:43:32      "message" : "Forbidden"
10:43:32    } ]

User's permissions:

Any idea why still permissions issue on this?
